# Проблемы с получением страницы [cURL]

Tags: curl, php

Доброго времени суток!

У меня возникла проблема, которая по сей день не возникала. В общем я пытаюсь получить данные( контент главной страницы ) с помощью cURL с сайта http://fx-trend.com/ таким вот образом:

```
$url="http://fx-trend.com/";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; MyIE2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Но это не работает....что я только не перепробовал...ничего не получалось - белый лист. Помогите мне пожалуйста! Спасибо =)

---

**UPD:** попробовал получить контент тупо с помощью PHP, удивился:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://fx-trend.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера. in ...
```

Также пинговал сайт из виндовой консоли - результат то же: превышен интервал! Что это такое???

Comment: а ошибки какие? Что не работает?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Неужели никто не поможет.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пинг указанного сайта(хоста) действительно не проходит. Скорее всего потому, что системные администраторы сознательно запретили ECHO-ответы для ICMP-запросов, которые и отсылает утилита ping. Это делается довольно просто подкруткой некоторых ядерных параметров(Linux, FreeBSD).

Использовать curl не получается потому, что на данном сайте установлена какая-то хитрая защита от подобных утилит, при включении отладки видно, что там происходит несколько редиректов, установка кукисов, а в конце - редирект на URL

```
http://protection.dragonara.net/cookies.html?backurl=http://fx-trend.com/?drgn=3
```

который и вызывает отлуп по таймауту.

Как обойти эту защиту - я не знаю, это уже другая проблема, которую нужно исследовать отдельно. 
Для диагностики использовалась консольная версия curl с командной строкой вида:

```
curl -vv -L  http://fx-trend.com/
```

*Кстати*, консольная утилита wget смогла у меня забрать index.html из корня + другие страницы  данного сайта(например http://fx-trend.com/news/afm_181212/).

```
wget http://fx-trend.com/
```

Как вариант, можно использовать её, породив процесс, затем забрав данные из файла или пайпа.

Answer (score 2):

[@LOLPADT](/users/9197/lolpadt) пинги закрыты просто.

На сайте, видимо, хитрая система аутентификации. Сначала, видимо, сайт проверяет наличие сессии, если есть - дает доступ. Если нет - то происходит редирект на страницу `http://fx-trend.com/?drgn=1`

Дальше, по всей видимости, происходит запись как на клиенте и последующая их проверка на сайте.

Comment: Да, попробовал из никсовой консоли "покурлить", получая предварительно заголовки - действительно редирект! Меня эта система защиты одновременно и вчечатляет и огорчает( ведь данные я вытянуть не могу... ). Спасибо вам!

Comment: Интересно так же было бы узнать, что бы вы предприняли в этом случае? Если, например, надо "позарез" получать контент страницы такого вот закрытого извне сайта из PHP.

Comment: @LOLPADT что-то что-то? Сделал бы так, чтобы скрипт получал эту страницу :-)

Comment: Ну и как же?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в cookies (вернее в том что Вы не включаете их в curl)
Попробуйте так:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

Answer (score 0):

wget http://fx-trend.com прекрасно работает. Вот логи процесса получения:

wget http://fx-trend.com
--2012-12-22 10:19:09--  http://fx-trend.com/
Resolving fx-trend.com... 91.205.41.168
Connecting to fx-trend.com|91.205.41.168|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://fx-trend.com/?drgn=1 [following]
--2012-12-22 10:19:11--  http://fx-trend.com/?drgn=1
Reusing existing connection to fx-trend.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html?drgn=1”

```
[    <=>                                                                                                              ] 29,138      42.5K/s   in 0.7s
```

2012-12-22 10:19:12 (42.5 KB/s) - “index.html?drgn=1” saved [29138]